# ElasticSearch - Too many open files

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I know that this is a known and discussed problem, but I would just like to get the dimensions right here:

I am running `ElasticSearch 2.4` on a single `Ubuntu Sever 16.04 node (12 cores, 256G ram)`. I have increased `ulimit to > 130k` (and verified via _nodes/stats/process).

I have two indices with 10 shards each (since multiple nodes will join the cluster soon).

Now I am writing with up to 900 concurrent Java TransportClients which leads to a collapse of the ElasticSearch server within seconds, throwing a "Too many open files" Exception.

Am I missing something here? Are 900 concurrent writes too much for a single instance to handle? Or are 10 shards too many for one node?

Comment: How many segments files are in total on this node? Your 900 concurrent Java clients live on the same machine as the ES node?

Comment: The query to find out the segments count: `GET /_nodes/stats/indices?filter_path=**.segments.count`

Comment: @AndreiStefan there are 469 segments, the 900 clients reside on a remote cluster.

Comment: And 'max_file_descriptors' value does reflect what you have set in the OS?

Comment: How do the remote clients access this cluster? Interested in how many network connections each opens... those do count against file descriptors limit. For example, if each request from a single client is a new connection which forgets to close it, then you may have a problem.

Comment: max_file_descriptors are the exact ulimit that i have set. I have increased the ulimit to 1M and re-created the indices with 1 shard each which seemed to have stabilized the ES node. Apparently every connected TransportClient results in a constant ~1000 open file descriptors on ES. I am not entirely sure how many HTTP connections each of them maintains, since I am using the ES Java API and there seems to be an ongoing ticket about that. Overall this solution seems very shaky to me as I am not entirely sure about what is going on...

Comment: Hm... that must be network sockets being opened?... I don't see why ES itself would open ~1000 file descriptors for each client access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what turned out to be the case:

- Connecting via the Java TransportClient creates a huge overhead. It does not use the HTTP REST API but an ES binary protocol. (as explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-interfacing-elasticsearch-picking-client))

  - Queries via TransportClient are negligibly faster than via REST.
  - The TransportClient creates a thread-pool on the client which as of now is non-configurable. It will maintain several connections so the nodes and is able to cope with failover retrieve cluster-statistics, etc. This leads to a considerable long-term load on the client.
  - In our case every additional connected TransportClient produced ~1000 open file descriptors on the ES machine.

We switched to [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest) Client which significantly reduced the load on both client and server. 900 concurrently active clients now result in <2000 file descriptors on the server.

Thanks to [Andrei Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3498062/andrei-stefan) for pointing us into the right direction.